# Change color of selected element - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. 
I'm trying to change the color of one particular "li" that was selected, but instead it changes color of all "li".

Also when another "li" is clicked I want the first "i" to be not active again.

here is the code:  http://codepen.io/polinaz/pen/zNJKqO

```
var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { color: ''}
  },
  changeColor: function(){
    var newColor = this.state.color == '' ? 'blue' : '';
    this.setState({ color : newColor})
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <li style={{background:this.state.color}} onClick={this.changeColor}>one</li>
         <li style={{background:this.state.color}} onClick={this.changeColor}>two</li>
         <li style={{background:this.state.color}} onClick={this.changeColor}>three</li>


      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <List/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you don't have any identifiers on you list items you activate/deactivate them all every time. You need to reference each of them in a different way, then you can set the color individually. This is one example

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { active: null}
  },

  toggle: function(position){
    if (this.state.active === position) {
      this.setState({active : null})
    } else {
      this.setState({active : position})
    }
  },
  
  myColor: function(position) {
    if (this.state.active === position) {
      return "blue";
    }
    return "";
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <li style={{background: this.myColor(0)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(0)}}>one</li>
        <li style={{background: this.myColor(1)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(1)}}>two</li>
        <li style={{background: this.myColor(2)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(2)}}>three</li>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <List/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Nice use of that `position` parameter! I've never used ReactJS before, so I can't explain it fully and post an answer, but here is another way, by giving `li`s their own component: http://codepen.io/blex41/pen/ZLMBzQ