# Render only selected element, React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

I am trying to toggle class in one of my react component.
The idea is to add class when the mouse enter and to remove the class when the mouse leave only in the element only the element in where the user perform the actions. However this is not the case as when the action is being performed all the element with the function are behaving equally.

This is my code so far:

```
export default class Projects extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHovered : false
    }
  }
  //handle mouse enter
  handleMouseEnter = () =>{
    this.setState({
      isHovered : true
    });
  }
  //handle mouse leave
  handleMouseLeave = () =>{
    this.setState({
      isHovered : false
    });
  }
//render component
  render(){
    let display = "";
    if(this.state.isHovered === true){
      display = "active";
    }else{
      display = "disable";
    }

    return(
      <section className="projects">
        {/*section project wrapper*/}
        <div className="p-wrapper">
            <h1 className="title">Projects</h1>
            <hr/>
            {/*projet wrapper*/}
            <div className="projects-wrapper">
              {/*project item wrapper*/}
              <div className="project-item" onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>{/*FMA Web development*/}
                <div className={"p-description " + display}>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure quos dolorem, ipsa eaque minima saepe fugit hic libero recusandae! Obcaecati esse odit id incidunt vitae aperiam dicta atque blanditiis sint?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="p-image">
                  <img src="asset/img/fma_web.png" alt="FMA Web Development"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="project-item" onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>{/*Web development using php*/}
                <div className={"p-description " + display}>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure quos dolorem, ipsa eaque minima saepe fugit hic libero recusandae! Obcaecati esse odit id incidunt vitae aperiam dicta atque blanditiis sint?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="p-image">
                  <img src="asset/img/web_dev_php.png" alt="FMA Web Development Using PHP"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="project-item" onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>{/*Movie Catalog*/}
                <div className={"p-description " + display}>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure quos dolorem, ipsa eaque minima saepe fugit hic libero recusandae! Obcaecati esse odit id incidunt vitae aperiam dicta atque blanditiis sint?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="p-image">
                  <img src="asset/img/movie_catalog.png" alt="Movie Catalog"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

I have read the use of key in the documentation and read other question especially this one [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101150/change-color-of-selected-element-react),however when I try to implement I do not get the desired result.

===========================

## EDIT

This is what I get now.
[image]

As you can see when I hover both of the element triggers.

This is my CSS Code:

```
/*Projects Start*/
.projects{
  width: 100%;
}

.p-wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}
.projects-wrapper{
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.project-item{
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 37px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.84);
}
.p-description{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.61);
  color: white;
}
.p-description p {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.p-title{
  margin: 1rem;
}
.active{
  display: block;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
.disable {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Look at how the functions are bound in the link you reference.  You're setting and referencing state for the whole `Projects` component.  Instead you want to either be specifying which element is hovered (the answer in your link) or using another component for each `project-item` that has it's own `hovered` state (the further comment by blex).

Comment: if you just wants a different styling when mouse is hovered over the element why not use a css solution like `.element:hover{...}` ?

Comment: @Sagivb.g basically the class p-description is hidden (display : none) at the beginning of the rendering, it will be available shown (display : block) only when the user will hover.

Comment: with `display:none` you **can't** trigger mouse events

Comment: @Sagivb.g I am not triggering the element using css properties. I have included the css and a image for a better explanation of the issue

Comment: you won't be able to trigger it via javascript

Comment: so how can I do it?

Comment: the issue is that all of the elements have the very same css class being toggled, via the same state object. When that state get's updated by one event, it does not look to which element triggered it, it does as it is supposed to and updates. Since ALL the elements are looking at a (shared)  state, they all update. The easiest way to fix this is to create a separate component that you can reuse for each `project-item`. That component should have a state that toggles when it is hovered, this effectively scopes the behavior to an individual element.

Comment: could you please show/link me an example?