# Toggle class only selected element, React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, toggle

I am trying to toggle class in one of my react component. At the beginning of the stage the element will be represented image and a hidden (disable) description. Whenever the user hover the element I want to add the class display only to the element hovered and not all the child components.
In jquery usually I would have done $(this).addClass("display"), but in react I cannot figure it out.

I have seen many post and tutorial but could not find anything in regards.
This is my code so far:

Parent component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem';

let projects = [
  {
    name: 'Web Development Using PHP',
    techUsed : [
      'HTML5',
      'CSS3',
      'PHP'
    ],
    link : 'sample_link',
    img : 'asset/img/movie_catalog.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Movie Catalog',
    techUsed : [
      'HTML5',
      'CSS3',
      'ReactJS',
      'JavaSript',
      'RESTAPI'
    ],
    link : 'sample_link',
    img : 'asset/img/fma_web.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Web Development',
    techUsed : [
      'HTML5',
      'CSS3'
    ],
    link : 'sample_link',
    img : 'asset/img/fma_web.png'
  }
];

//Projects Component
export default class Projects extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      proj : projects
    }
  }

  //handle mouse enter 
  handleMouseEnter = () =>{
    this.setState({
      isHovered : true
    });
  }
  //handle mouse leave
  handleMouseLeave = () =>{
    this.setState({
      isHovered : false
    });
  }

  //render the component
  render(){


    return(
      <section className="projects">
        {/*section project wrapper*/}
        <div className="p-wrapper">
          <h1 className="title">Projects</h1>
          <hr/>
          {/*projet wrapper*/}
          <ProjectItem projects = {this.state.proj} /> 
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

//export the component
export default class ProjectItem extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isHovered : false
        }
    }
    //handle mouse enter 
    handleMouseEnter = () =>{
        this.setState({
            isHovered : true
        });
    }
    //handle mouse leave
    handleMouseLeave = () =>{
        this.setState({
            isHovered : false
        });
    }
    //render the project item component
    render(){
        let display = "";
        //assign the class based on the state of display
        if(this.state.isHovered === true){
            display = "active";
        }else{
            display = "disable";
        }

        return(
            <div className="projects-wrapper">
                {
                    this.props.projects.map((project, index) =>{
                        return(
                            <div className="project-item"  key={index} onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>{/*FMA Web development*/}
                                <div className={"p-description " + display}>
                                <p>{project.name}</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure quos dolorem, ipsa eaque minima saepe fugit hic libero recusandae! Obcaecati esse odit id incidunt vitae aperiam dicta atque blanditiis sint?</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="p-image">
                                <img src="asset/img/fma_web.png" alt="FMA Web Development"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

CSS

```
/*Projects Start*/
.projects{
  width: 100%;
}

.p-wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}
.projects-wrapper{
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.project-item{
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 37px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.84);
}
.p-description{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(43, 40, 40, 0.61);
  color: white;
}
.p-description p {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.p-title{
  margin: 1rem;
}
.active{
  display: block;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
.disable {
  display: none;
}
```

Image-Illustration of the issue.
[image]

I might be against the rules of the forum as I have already asked the question over here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978329/render-only-selected-element-react-js), However I have not gotten any concrete answer. Therefore, I am asking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the local state of `ProjectItem` is applied to each project in `this.props.projects.map`. I would suggest instead mapping the projects in the `Projects` parent component instead, like this:

```js
this.state.proj.map((proj, index) => {
  return <ProjectItem project = {proj} /> 
}
```

and then refactoring your `ProjectItem` component. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let container be the class you wish toggle when hover

```
return(    
    <div className={"row" + (this.state.hover?"container":"")} onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover} style={{borderStyle:'solid',borderWidth:'0.3px',padding:'5px 0 0 0'}}>
        something
        </div>)
```

and create function which will change the state when mouse enter and leave

```
toggleHover(e){
        console.log("is hovering")
        this.setState({"hover":!this.state.hover})
    }
```

and

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            hover:false
        }
        this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this)
    }
```

hope this help. this is working on my pc let me know if you have some trouble